# Apply filters on date format

Tags: date-time

I use a Wordpress Theme where the format date and time is directly coded in 2 formats :

```
<?php the_time('d M'); ?>

<?php the_time('H:i'); ?>
```

What I want :

- Display the date and the time as defined in wordpress options
- I don't want to create modified templates in the Child Theme
- I prefer to use functions.php for that

I've already added in functions.php this code that works :

```
add_filter( 'the_time', 'changer_date_format', 10, 1 ); //override time display
function changer_date_format( $ladate ) {
    global $post;
    $ladate = get_post_time( get_option( 'date_format' ), false, $post, true ); 
    return $ladate;
}
```

But the problem with this solution is that **I can just apply either the date or the time wordpress option for the 2 cases** the_time('d M') and the_time('H:i'), and I would like to apply separately:

- the TIME wordpress option on the case the_time('H:i')
- the DATE wordpress option for the case the_time('d M')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the code reference [`the_time`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_time/) filter recieves two parameters - `$get_the_time` and `$format`. You can use the latter to determine which formatting option to use.

```
add_filter( 'the_time', 'changer_date_format', 10, 2 );
function changer_date_format( $ladate, $format ) {
  global $post;
  if ( 'd M' === $format ) {
    return get_post_time( get_option( 'date_format' ), false, $post, true ); 
  } else if ( 'H:i' === $format ) {
    return get_post_time( get_option( 'time_format' ), false, $post, true ); 
  } else {
    return $ladate;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Antti, it works !